# Loading JSON from url in Ironpython

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib, ironpython

Im writing a code in Ironpython and I would like to read a url that contains json in it.

My code looks as following:

```
import urllib
import json

link = 'http://........'
response = urllib.urlopen(link)
data = json.load(response)
```

However, i'm receiving the following error:

```
IOError: [Errno socket error] [Errno errors while validating certificate chain: ] RemoteCertificateNameMismatch, RemoteCertificateChainErrors
```

Also, tried using `urllib2` and im getting the same error.

Any idea why it might happen? (from what I understand I cant use packages of urllib3 since it is in Ironpython).

Thank you.

Comment: Tryh `urllib.urlopen(link, context=ssl._create_unverified_context())` to see if the error vanishes. And off course `import ssl`

Comment: It worked, took pretty much time but worked. Is there any risk in using this solution tho?